# How to see relationship model in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any diagram one can look in postgreSQL to see what columns different tables join and associate on?

Comment: Not sure what you want. A query builder or an entity diagram model? none are available on pgAdmin so maybe you need a thrid party software. If you use .net Entity Framework you can get the ER diagram.

Comment: Yes an entity relationship diagram (schema diagram) which shows the table relationships. Is it possible in pgadmin 4?

Comment: didnt know there was pgAdmin 4. .... 3 doesnt have anything for that

Comment: Try DBVisualizer or SchemaSpy. Both are good extracting ER diagrams from your postgres database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try DBVisualizer or SchemaSpy. Both are good extracting ER diagrams from your postgres database. – cachique Jul 29 at 18:35